# How to use the IConfigurationStore parameter in Windsor Installer?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

The [`Install` method of `IWindsorInstaller`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Installers&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) has an `IConfigurationStore store` parameter. I can't find anywhere a code example where this parameter is **actually used**. What can it be used for? Can you please give me a usage example, or point me to some code where it is used?

Searching the web doesn't help, because `IConfigurationStore` is mentioned zillions of times, but I haven't found a single place where it was used.

Thanks!

Comment: 7 years later and there's still nothing out there :(

Answer (score 1):

Just as the name says, it gives you access to Windsor's configuration (properties, components, parameters, service overrides, etc). I'd say configuration is more commonly used in facilities than installers, so you might want to take a look at some facilities as reference.

As a contrived example, suppose you have an installer with several components related to some web service. You might make this installer configurable WRT the service endpoint so you could define the endpoint in Castle's XML config, thus avoiding recompliation if the endpoint changes.

Comment: Thank you, Mauricio. I understand the need, I just can't figure out what syntax to use. `IConfigurationStore` has so many methods and properties that I don't know where to start. And searching on Google doesn't help, because `IConfigurationStore` is mentioned zillions of times, but I haven't found a single place where it was used.